# Virtualenv Python Windows

Tags: python, django, pip

I'm having problems featured in this question: [Pip with Python 2.7 and 3.4 on Windows Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29798334/pip-with-python-2-7-and-3-4-on-windows-machine)

But the question I have now is this.  When I use `virtualenvwrapper`, `mkvirtualenv`, `lsvirtualenv`, and `rmvirtualenv` all work.  But work on 'venv name' doesn't do anything.  And when I don't use the wrapper, doing *venvname\Scripts\activate* activates the `virtualenv` but the prefix before my name in the shell is white instead of green, not sure what that means. But the main problem is this, and may be related to all of the other stuff.  When I begin to install stuff using  either *requirements.txt* or manually installing things via pip, all of the installed packages end up in *C:\Python27\lib\site-packages* rather than *C:\Python34\lib\site-packages* or whatever.  I assume it has to do with `pip3` being located at             *C:\Python27\site-packages rather than C:\Python34*.

Also, when I load a `virtualenv` and begin to install things it uses the packages in *C:\Python27\lib\site-packages* instead of those installed into the virtualenv's site-packages folder.  This causes lots of issues.  For example earlier I was installing django and specifying 1.8, but it kept saying Django 1.5.3 was installed.  And even uninstalling and re-installing didn't help.

Anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: You're basically asking us to debug your whole development environment - this simply isn't practical.

Comment: Improved formatting, removed irrelevant ending

Comment: Thanks for the formatting help.  And no I am not asking that.  I was asking what could possibly be causing python to not use the virtualenv packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to overcome the problem by realiasing pip correctly and using the flag --ignore-installed.  Seems having two python versions installed is an issue if you don't take extra care to set it up.